# Context-dependent attacker

Tags: attacks

In the context of the following statement what is meant by context-dependent attacker?

> The MySQL Client contains an overflow condition in client/mysql.cc. The issue is triggered as user-supplied input is not properly validated when handling server versions. This may allow a context-dependent attacker to cause a buffer overflow, resulting in a denial of service or potentially allowing the execution of arbitrary code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that this isn't the best wording. Essentially, it means that there are unusual circumstances in order to exploit this. In the specific case of this bug, you have to get the user to connect to a malicious server under your control, or Man-in-the-Middle a connection to a legitimate server.

The vulnerability is a simple stack overflow on the version string which the server replies with. The client expects that the server will only reply with strings shorter than a fixed size, and then copies the entire string into a fixed-length buffer. If the string turns out to be larger than the buffer, it copies over the end, corrupting the stack.